# Discord.js: create Message object before sending

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to create a message object before actually sending it in the channel, is this possible?
I keep getting weird errors on this code:

```
var new_message = new Discord.Message(channel, {
    author: client.user,
    content: 'Hello, ' + message.author.username + '!'
}, client);
console.info(new_message);
channel.send(new_message);
```

but that just gives me the error below.
The reason i want the message object, is so that i can easily add a reaction to it right after sending.

```
React-o-matic Discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Message.js:86
  this.author = this.client.users.add(data.author, !data.webhook_id);
                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at Message._patch (React-o-matic Discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Message.js:86:39)
    at new Message (React-o-matic Discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Message.js:44:20)
    at Client.<anonymous> (React-o-matic Discord/bot.js:18:35)
    at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (React-o-matic Discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (React-o-matic Discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (React-o-matic Discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (React-o-matic Discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (React-o-matic Discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (React-o-matic Discord/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
```

Comment: Is `client` working correctly?

Comment: I've never used this library before, but it looks like the function you're calling might be expecting `client` to have some field named `users` (plural) which it doesn't.

Comment: yeah client works fine i think, im able to to client for other purposes, but note the error is referring to some core files, not to code ive been editing, so probably im missing data or something... but i cant find anything about `new Discord.Message` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var msg = new Discord.Message(client, {
    id: message.id,
    type: message.type,
    content: message.content,
    author: client.user,
    pinned: message.pinned,
    tts: message.tts,
    embeds: message.embeds,
    attachments: message.attachments,
    nonce: "123" // idfk
}, channel)
```

This is the minimum you need to create a Message object.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i wanted to know! But: How do you know this? Ive not been able to find any documentation stating this.

Comment: Glad to hear it helps! I found it by manually going over the _patch() function of the message object and seeing what is mendatory for the message object to be created. You can look for yourself here: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/Message.js#L29

Comment: i know its a bit late response, but how would you get message.id? by creating another message first? :P

Comment: I'm guessing they needed to parse message from one server to another. If not, there is a much easier way of just sending a message. :D
To answer your question, you most definitely can't create a message without giving it an ID, but i don't know about the requirements and if you can supply a custom ID.

Comment: I wonder if you can input a custom message.id and later refer to this custom message.id after sending a message.

Comment: No, replacing message.id without your own custom id does nothing. The new generated id is placed instead in the message.id .

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to solve my problem: use the .then() functionality:

```
channel.send('Hello, ' + message.author.username + '!')
    .then(function (sent_message) {
        console.info("message sent");
    });
```

This allows me to do basically the same! There is no documentation about the .send() command, but i tried, and it works haha

Comment: What do you mean there's no documentation on [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)?

Comment: Well, i guess i forgot to check the TextChannel page, hahaha, thanks!